# Using npgsql with CockroachDB and .Net Core

Tags: npgsql, cockroachdb

I successfully used npgsql (Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) to connect to PostgreSQL database. I have heard that same EF provider works well with CockroachDB. I am trying with it but need help to define connection string for **CockroachDB**. For PostgreSQL I have used following connection string:

```
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=<database>;Username=postgres;Password=<password>");
```

Does anybody know what should a connection string look like if I wish to connect it to **CockroachDB**?

Answer (score 1):

The connection string you mentioned is almost correct, you just need to add `Port=26257` as CockroachDB runs on a dedicated port.

If the Cockroach nodes are running securely, you'll also need to specify the [Security and Encryption](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) parameters.

You can find sample code to use npgsql to talk to CockroachDB in the [docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-csharp-app-with-cockroachdb.html), including the important "retry logic" section.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. That worked well. I am now struggling with generated query by the LINQ which is not compatible with CockroachDB. Though same query works well with PostgreSQL. Any idea if I have to do some more configuration in table schema mapping while EF creates models?

Comment: That's probably a separate question. That said, I don't know anything about LINQ. It's possible it's using statements CockroachDB does not support. You can [log the executed queries](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-faqs.html#how-do-i-log-sql-queries) and see which ones fail.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it finally. The problem was with EF entity and table name mapping in the OnModelCreating() event of the DataContext. When I changed the table name to lowercase it worked. E.g. modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("students");